# Problems converting a .PFX certificate to .PEM

Tags: ssl, pem, pfx

I work with certificates and occasionally need to convert a private certificate `.PFX` extension for `.PEM` extension, but I can only consume it in a webservice if it is generated without a password, that is, unprotected.

If I try to generate it with password (being the same password as or not of `.PFX` certificate), I can not consume it in webservice (I get the error `"403 - Forbidden"`).

Can you tell me why this occurs?

To generate it unprotected, I use the command below (through OpenSSL):

```
pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.pem -nodes
```

To generate it with password, I use this one:

```
pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.pem
```

I can not understand why the error occurs, since OpenSSL does not indicate a failure.

I use Windows environment, so I use an OpenSSL tool I found on the internet.